# iphone NSNumberFormatter work on simulator not on device os 4.2 while parsing

Tags: iphone, nsnumberformatter

This is a piece of code of terremoto from Craig Schamp .. works fine on simulator (os 4.2) but not on device.

```
self.currentEarthquake.magnitude = [formatter numberFromString:magString]; and

NSNumber *latituide = [formatter numberFromString:[comp objectAtIndex:0]];

NSNumber *longitude = [formatter numberFromString:[comp objectAtIndex:1]]
```

on device are null while on simulator have all the data .... here the all code ....my device is 3g with 4.2 
is NSNumberFormatter the problem ???

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
  //<title>M 5.8, Banda Sea</title>
  NSArray *components = [self.propertyValue componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
  if (components.count > 1) {
   // strip the M
   NSString *magString = [[[components objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1];

   NSLog(@"String %@",magString);

   NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
   self.currentEarthquake.magnitude = [formatter numberFromString:magString];
   self.currentEarthquake.place = [components objectAtIndex:1];
   [formatter release];

   NSLog(@"Magnetudine %@",self.currentEarthquake.magnitude);
   NSLog(@"Place %@",self.currentEarthquake.place);

   NSLocale *currentUsersLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
   NSLog(@"Current Locale: %@", [currentUsersLocale localeIdentifier]);

  }
 } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"updated"]) {
  //<updated>2008-04-29T19:10:01Z</updated>
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
  self.currentEarthquake.lastUpdate = [formatter dateFromString:self.propertyValue];
  [formatter release];

  NSLog(@"Date %@",self.currentEarthquake.lastUpdate);

 } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"georss:point"]) {
  NSArray *comp = [self.propertyValue componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
  NSLog(@"Comp %@",comp);

  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];


  NSNumber *latituide = [formatter numberFromString:[comp objectAtIndex:0]];
  NSLog(@"Latitude %@",latituide);
  NSNumber *longitude = [formatter numberFromString:[comp objectAtIndex:1]];
  [formatter release];
  CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latituide.floatValue
                longitude:longitude.floatValue];
  self.currentEarthquake.location = location;
  [location release];

  NSLog(@"Location %@",location);
 } else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
  [(id)[self delegate] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addEarthquake:)
             withObject:self.currentEarthquake
             waitUntilDone:NO];
 }
```

2010-12-05 03:46:45.738 Terremoto[251:307] Comp (
    "41.9022",
    "12.4579"
)
2010-12-05 03:46:45.745 Terremoto[251:307] Latitude (null)

2010-12-05 03:46:45.847 Terremoto[251:307] Location <+0.00000000, +0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 05/12/10 03:46:45 GMT-03:00

2010-12-05 03:46:45.854 Terremoto[251:307] String 5.0

2010-12-05 03:46:45.864 Terremoto[251:307] Magnetudine (null)

2010-12-05 03:46:45.868 Terremoto[251:307] Place  Hotel Ergife

2010-12-05 03:46:45.871 Terremoto[251:307] Current Locale: it_IT

2010-12-05 03:46:45.892 Terremoto[251:307] Date 2010-10-14 14:35:18 +0000

2010-12-05 03:46:45.898 Terremoto[251:307] Comp (
    "-6.1020",
    "127.5017"
)

device log

Answer (score 6):

The reason it doesn't work is most likely that in your locale (Italian), the period "." is not the valid decimal separator.

Call `-[NSNumberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:]` to set it to the correct value.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was suspecting that cos on device current local was it-IT and simulator  en_US ... just add [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."]; and work fine ...thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in the same context (parsing coordinates). I'm on iOS 4.3. My mac an the iPad I used are both set to german, so IMO the formatter should behave the same way, but it didn't.

I ended up with using this:

```
 pi.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(NSString *)[coords objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]];
```

That works on the simulator and on the device.